# jq: how to add the key of each element in a list into its value

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON input looks like:

```
{
    "name1":{
        "type1":1,
        "type2":2
    },
    "name2":{
        "type2":3,
        "type3":4
    }
}
```

I'd like to use jq to convert it into something like:

```
[
    {
        "name":"name1",
        "count":[
            {
                "type":"type1"
                "number":1
            },
            {
                "type":"type2"
                "number":2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"name2",
        "count":[
            {
                "type":"type2"
                "number":3
            },
            {
                "type":"type3"
                "number":4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

not sure if this is possible to do?

https://jqplay.org/s/b7ByAsQ571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the elegant of filters, but does what you need. All you need is a nested `to_entries[]` transformation and build the JSON on top of it.

```
jq '[ to_entries[] | 
      { "name": .key, 
        "count": [ .value | to_entries[] | { "type": .key, "number": .value } ]
      }
    ]' json
```

[jq-play](https://jqplay.org/s/xClPHmIsTZ) snippet for the same.